# Use WebClient instead of HttpClient

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, httpclient, webclient

I have two projects with version 4.0 and 4.5 and I wanted to use the following function for both of them but unfortunately, HttpClient is only available for 4.5

```
public async Task<SlackTest> GetAccessToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string code)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = ApiUrl + "/oauth.access?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=" + code;
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                SlackTest slackTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackTest>(content);
                string accessToken = slackTest.AccessToken;
                string urlUserIdentity = "https://slack.com/api/users.identity?token=" + accessToken;
                var responseUser = await client.GetAsync(urlUserIdentity);
                string contentUserIdentity = await responseUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                SlackTest2 slack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackTest2>(contentUserIdentity);             System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Srishti\Desktop\AccessTokenSlack.txt", accessToken);
                return slackTest;
            }
        }
```

So now I need to do the same thing using WebClient which I have never used. Could someone help me with this and probably give a headstart on how to go about this.

I started to as under:

```
string url = ApiUrl + "/oauth.access?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=" + code;
                var response = await client.DownloadDataAsync(url);
```

But the intellisense doesn't give me the option of using DownloadDataTaskAsync.
Can we not use webclient with Tasks and awaits?

Comment: You want someone to write your code for you? That's not a good thing to do on Stack Overflow. Sounds more like you want to hire a contractor if you don't know what you're doing. If you want to make a valid question here, then *make an attempt* to do what you're trying to do and only post here if it doesn't work, making sure to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: For sample code, CodeProject might help, or a Google search.  For SO, please read [tour] and [ask] to see what kind of questions to ask here.

Comment: Oh, sorry I already added a sample of what I am doing. Or want to do.

Comment: @D-johnAnshani Please review [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Suggesting someone use `async void` is a very bad idea.

Comment: @D-johnAnshani The accepted answer there is terrible. Please review the link I provided you.

Comment: Can we not use async Task. Sorry am new to asynchronous programming and want to keep my code the same as much as possible.

Comment: WebClient has synchronous and asynchronous methods for all its operations.

Comment: check my answer @srishtijaiswal and mark as answer if you like it

Comment: @mason could you tell me why cannot I use DownloadDataTaskAsync method? It is not showing in the intellisense and when I write it, it gives e an error line.

Comment: Async/await and the Task Based Asynchronous stuff wasn't added until .NET 4.5. Is there a reason you're still using .NET 4.0?

Comment: @mason I am bound to use .Net 4.0 as the project is my company's project which is 8 years old and they need it for xp users. Sorry If I am vague and much informative. So you man I cannot use Task with webclient and not void as well.

Comment: Okay so why don't you just use the synchronous methods available on the WebClient? What's preventing you from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use httpclient because you are missing nugget package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Comment: I cannot use http client with the other project as it is version 4.0 and changing it to version 4.5 is a longer process.

Comment: and what stops you from downloading the nugget?Download the nugget in 4,0 version without upgrading.

Comment: I did that but it gives me an error of conflicting versions

Comment: Remove System.net.http from your references in the 4.0 project and add the nuget. In your code make sure you have this  "using System.Net.Http"

Comment: Did that too. Doesn't work either. The only solution that my senior found was using WebClient.